# Unable to setup Facebook authentication with Flutter and Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I am trying to code a Sign-in page with authentication using Firebase.
I've got properly working email and google authentication functionality but I am stuck on Facebook method.

I did everything as Facebook's quick start says:

**1.** Added to app/build.gradle dependencies

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'
```

**2.** Set package name ( with change_app_package_name library ) and set it in Developers Facebook site according to my AndroidManifest.xml file.

**3.** Generate Key Hash for development on Linux using command:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

**4.** Enable Sign On in either Firebase Console and Developers.Facebook.

**5.** Create strings.xml file located in android/app/src/main/res/values with content below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name"> <MyAppName> </string>
    <string name="facebook_app_id"> <MyAppId> </string>
    <string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme"> fb<MyAppId> </string>
</resources>
```

**6.** Add required content to AndroidManifest.xml. This is my whole file:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.tiver.app">
    <application
            android:label="Tiver"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:launchMode="singleTop"
                android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
                android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                    android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                    android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
            />
            <meta-data
                    android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                    android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
            />
        </activity>
        <meta-data
                android:name="flutterEmbedding"
                android:value="2" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
                   android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
                  android:configChanges=
                          "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
                  android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
                android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
                android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

I implemented my *signInWithFacebook* function in the following way:

```dart
@override
  Future<Either<AuthFailure, Unit>> signInWithFacebook() async {
    final result = await _facebookAuth.login();
    if (result.status == LoginStatus.success) {
      final credential =
          FacebookAuthProvider.credential(result.accessToken!.token);
      print(credential);
      try {
        await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
        return right(unit);
      } on PlatformException catch (error) {
        if (error.code == 'invalid-credential') {
          return left(const AuthFailure.invalidEmailOrPassword());
        } else {
          return left(const AuthFailure.serverError());
        }
      }
    }

    return left(const AuthFailure.cancelledByUser());
  }
```

Every other signing method was implemented in the similar way and it works properly.
I use _facebookAuth insted of FacebookAuth.instance, with help of **getIt** and **Injectable** - I registered it inside *injection.dart* file :

```dart
GetIt s1 = GetIt.instance;

Future<void> init() async {
  s1.registerLazySingleton(() => FacebookAuth.instance);
}
```

Injections seems to be proper, it doesn't logs any errors and I think that it is needed to properly perform unit tests.

In my Firebase Console I have sign in with Facebook enabled with properly filled App Id and App Secret. I also used generated url redirect and specified in my Facebook App dasboard.

I double checked if I did every single step required to authentication, researched over error messages I receive and I still have no idea why do I still receive following errors:

*It occurs when app is initialized.*

```
{HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, subErrorCode: 33, errorType: GraphMethodException, errorMessage: Unsupported get request. Object with ID '<MyAppId>' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api}
```

*It occurs after the process of Facebook authentication - I click on the sign in with facebook button, I get redirected to facebook's page, I properly see my application name I log in, it redirects me back to my sign in page in application and logs following error:*

```
E/flutter ( 7488): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Unhandled error [firebase_auth/invalid-credential] The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired. [ Unsuccessful debug_token response from Facebook: {"error":{"message":"Error validating application. Cannot get application info due to a system error.","type":"OAuthException","code":190,"fbtrace_id":"ArGSne7K9z7tMuLSPceuJy8"}} ] occurred in Instance of 'SignInFormBloc'.
E/flutter ( 7488): #0      MethodChannelFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential (package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase_auth.dart:422:7)
E/flutter ( 7488): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7488): #1      FirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential (package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart:465:7)
E/flutter ( 7488): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7488): #2      FirebaseAuthFacade.signInWithFacebook (package:food_informer/infrastructure/auth/firebase_auth_facade.dart:92:9)
E/flutter ( 7488): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7488): #3      SignInFormBloc.mapEventToState.<anonymous closure> (package:food_informer/application/auth/sign_in_form/sign_in_form_bloc.dart:62:22)
E/flutter ( 7488): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7488): 
E/flutter ( 7488): #0      BlocBase.onError.<anonymous closure> (package:bloc/src/bloc.dart:389:7)
E/flutter ( 7488): #1      BlocBase.onError (package:bloc/src/bloc.dart:390:6)
E/flutter ( 7488): #2      _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1378:47)
E/flutter ( 7488): #3      _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1272:19)
E/flutter ( 7488): #4      _CustomZone.runBinaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1178:7)
E/flutter ( 7488): #5      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendError.sendError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:360:15)
E/flutter ( 7488): #6      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:378:16)
E/flutter ( 7488): #7      _BufferingStreamSubscription._addError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:280:7)
E/flutter ( 7488): #8      _SyncBroadcastStreamController._sendError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:393:20)
E/flutter ( 7488): #9      _BroadcastStreamController._forEachListener (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:323:15)
E/flutter ( 7488): #10     _SyncBroadcastStreamController._sendError (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:392:5)
E/flutter ( 7488): #11     _BroadcastStreamController._addError (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:290:5)
E/flutter ( 7488): #12     _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1378:47)
E/flutter ( 7488): #13     _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1272:19)
E/flutter ( 7488): #14     _CustomZone.runBinaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1178:7)
E/flutter ( 7488): #15     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendError.sendError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:360:15)
E/flutter ( 7488): #16     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:378:16)
E/flutter ( 7488): #17     _BufferingStreamSubscription._addError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:280:7)
E/flutter ( 7488): #18     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._addError (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:128:11)
E/flutter ( 7488): #19     _ForwardingStream._handleError (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:95:10)
E/flutter ( 7488): #20     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleError (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:157:13)
E/flutter ( 7488): #21     _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1378:47)
E/flutter ( 7488): #22     _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1272:19)
E/flutter ( 7488): #23     _CustomZone.runBinaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1178:7)
E/flutter ( 7488): #24     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendError.sendError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:360:15)
E/flutter ( 7488): #25     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:378:16)
E/flutter ( 7488): #26     _DelayedError.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:602:14)
E/flutter ( 7488): #27     _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:706:11)
E/flutter ( 7488): #28     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:663:7)
E/flutter ( 7488): #29     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1346:47)
E/flutter ( 7488): #30     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1258:19)
E/flutter ( 7488): #31     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1162:7)
E/flutter ( 7488): #32     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1202:23)
E/flutter ( 7488): #33     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1354:13)
E/flutter ( 7488): #34     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1258:19)
E/flutter ( 7488): #35     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1162:7)
E/flutter ( 7488): #36     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1202:23)
E/flutter ( 7488): #37     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
E/flutter ( 7488): #38     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
E/flutter ( 7488):
```

*I seen a few stack overflow posts about those errors, but none of the answers worked for me. I would be grateful for any advice on how to solve it. Please comment if any other information about my implementation is needed - I will try to deliver it as soon as possible.*

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same error, but then I put the privacy policy URL in the basic setting of facebook developer account, and then turn on the live mode of the application. That works for me